# XML-RPC on Android Tablet (battery consumption)

Tags: android, xml, rpc, battery, consumption

I want to implement a XML-RPC server on an android tablet.
I have read some about web services and their great battery consumption.

How big is the battery comsumption with a XML-RPC server? Is it to big for a mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML-RPC require HTTP server and XML-RPC requests handler.

For HTTP server, you can use some small HTTP server, like [NanoHTTPD](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd)
It has all the features, required on implement XML-RPC and it's very good suited for mobile devices.
Memory, CPU and battery consumption by NanoHTTPD is minimal.

Battery consumption depends on how many requests you will have. If you will issue request every second, it will drain battery signifantly.

Comment: If you care about battery consumption, and you have rare events, you can consider using device notify, instead of polling. E.g. when some event occurs, Android device send signal to host (not host polls Android device for data).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how often you make calls to your server. With a smart caching management, and correct usage, battery should be good.

Comment: The XML_RPC server should be call if there are updates (XML-Files for an app). I think this happens not so often.